# definition of norm of the gradient on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given $(M,g)$ a Riemannian manifold, I am trying to come up with a natural way to define the norm of the gradient $grad f$ for a smooth function $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on $M$. I was thinking about doing it in a natural way, at each point $p \in M$

$|grad f|_p$ = $sup_{v \in T_p(M)} \frac{|gradf(v)|}{g(v,v)^{1/2}}$

But then this is dependent on $p \in M$. Is this the standard way to do it or is there some other way?

Comment: What about the gradient of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$? Do you already know a definition of its norm?

Comment: I do not. Where can I read up on it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of natural ways to take the norm of the vector field $X = \text{grad } f$. Pointwise, the norm of a vector is calculated as usual: $|X(p)|_g^2 = g(X(p), X(p))$. Then to take the norm of $X$, you use one of the various function space norms, such as $\|X\|_{C^k}$ for $k \geq 0$ if $M$ is compact (this is the sup norm when $k = 0$), or Sobolev norms $\|X\|_{H^k}$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ (note that $H^0 = L^2$).